# How to set a textarea to a variable that opens in a form on a new page

Tags: php, html, forms

As the title says I am trying to use the info in a form textarea as a variable.

To explain more of what I am trying, I want to enter a Youtube link in a text area and then click submit to cause it to open the video in a frame.

(I got the code for the link and the frame but i need to know how to make the page "reload / open a new page with the link in a frame" so plz tell me what does i do?

hopes its all the info you need :)

here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="input" action="?videolink=1" method="get">
 Url: <input type="text" name="hello">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

<?php
$url = ' THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE INFO FORM THE FORM TO BE :) ';
    $parts = explode('=', $url);
$url2 = $parts[1];

$url3 = trim($url2,"?\/-_.:,;*+}=])[({/&%€¤$#£@!<>");
    echo $url3;

$youtube = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/';
$video = $url3;
$vars = '&loop=1&autoplay=1';

 $test = ($youtube . $video . $vars);
    echo $test;

?>
<br>

 <iframe width="420" height="345"
 src="<? echo $test; ?>">
 </iframe>
 <p>hello</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add an id to your iframe, and your text input (remember there is a major difference between textarea and an input with type= text. Then use JS to set the src of the iFrame to the value of the input onSubmit of the form.

```
function setIFrame(){
  document.getElementById('iFrameID').src = document.getElementById('inputID').value;
  return false;
}

<form name="input" action="?videolink=1" method="get" onSubmit="setIFrame()">
```